# Ubuntu 15 on HP Pavilion dv6 3046eo

Tags: drivers, graphics

I have no graphic drivers for my HP Pavilion dv6 3046eo fitting to windows 10 and are considering to switch to ubuntu. Are there any known problems with the hardware listed below? (I checked the related questions for the dv6, but it was about some other hardware)

```
Microprocessor  
  2.8 GHz AMD Phenom II Dual-Core Processor N620  
Microprocessor Cache  
  Level 2 cache 2 MB  
Memory  
  6 GB DDR3 (1 x 2048 MB + 1 x 4096 MB)  
Memory Max  
  Supports up to 8 GB DDR3 memory  
Video Graphics  
  ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 Graphics (switchable)  
Video Memory  
  up to 3738 MB total graphics memory with 1 GB DDR3 dedicated 
Display  
  39.6 cm (15.6") diagonal High-Definition LED HP BrightView Display (1366 x 768)  
Hard Drive  
  640 GB SATA Hard Disk Drive 5400 rpm  
Multimedia Drive  
   SATA optical drive: LightScribe SuperMulti DVD±R/RW with Double Layer Support  
Network Card  
    Integrated 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet LAN  
Wireless Connectivity  
    Bluetooth wireless networking
    802.11 b/g/n  
5-in-1 integrated Digital Media Reader for Secure Digital cards, MultiMedia cards, Memory Stick, Memory Stick Pro or xD Picture cards
```

Comment: It should work OK.